# Load a .ttf file as a font in PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt6

```
font_db = QFontDatabase()
font_id = font_db.addApplicationFont("test.ttf")
```

This is deprecated in PyQt6 and gives the warning

```
 DeprecationWarning: QFontDatabase.QFontDatabase() is deprecated
  font_db = QFontDatabase()
```

what to use instead of QFontDatabase to load a font from a .ttf file.

Comment: As explained in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfontdatabase-obsolete.html#QFontDatabase): "Call the class methods as static functions instead.". Don't create the instance, just use `QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by musicamante calling the class methods as static functions works.
So instead of this :

```
font_db = QFontDatabase()
font_id = font_db.addApplicationFont('test.ttf')
```

It should be done like this :

```
QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('test.ttf')
```